# ImportError: No module named 'base' (laspy, python 3.5)

Tags: python

I have a python 3.5 and when I try to import file from laspy I got the following problem:

```
import laspy
import laspy.file


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Geri\Desktop\Sync\pythonlas\envisecondwrite.py", line 2, in <module>
    import laspy.file
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\laspy\file.py", line 1, in <module>
    import base
ImportError: No module named 'base'
```

When I played a little with it:

```
import laspy
from laspy import base
import laspy.file

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Geri\Desktop\Sync\pythonlas\envisecondwrite.py", line 2, in <module>
    from laspy import base
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\laspy\base.py", line 2, in <module>
    from header import HeaderManager, Header, VLR, EVLR, ExtraBytesStruct
ImportError: No module named 'header'
```

Then I tried:

```
import laspy
from laspy import header
from laspy import base
import laspy.file

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Geri\Desktop\Sync\pythonlas\envisecondwrite.py", line 2, in <module>
    from laspy import header
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\laspy\header.py", line 3, in <module>
    import util
ImportError: No module named 'util'
```

When I tried this with the util, it simpye doesn't find it.

```
import laspy
from laspy import util
from laspy import header
from laspy import base
import laspy.file

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Geri\Desktop\Sync\pythonlas\envisecondwrite.py", line 3, in <module>
    from laspy import header
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\laspy\header.py", line 3, in <module>
    import util
ImportError: No module named 'util'
```

I'm pretty sure something wrong with the directories. Please help, thanks.

PATH:

```
C:\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Python35\;
```

**Update:**
I uninstalled the 2.7 python and reinstalled the 3.5 Same issue...

Comment: How did you install this module?

Comment: with pip:

pip install laspy

Comment: For your information: I have a 2.7 python which is built in the ArcGIS on the computer. I changed the path to the 3.5

Comment: What do you mean when you say you changed the path? What did you do exactly?

Comment: Well I deleted the old path from environmental variables. The python 3.5 already put its path there.

Comment: My guess: The problem is that you used `pip` when you had python2 on the path, and now your installation is not found by python3. You need to reinstall laspy with pip for python3 now that you have python3 on your path.

Comment: I reinstalled it, and I can find the laspy files within the 3.5 directories

Comment: Can you add your full PATH to the question details?

Comment: I added it to the details

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve the problem by adding the following in the code:

```
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.append('C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\laspy')
```

**Update:**
I uninstalled the 3.5 and installed the 2.7 standalone.
It seem the system like that better, no issues.